# How to close a wxDialog so it doesn't prevent program from exiting

Tags: c++, dialog, wxwidgets

When I close all windows (frames/dialogs) the debugger keeps the program running.  That's the problem.
I want the program to close when the dialogs are closed.

I want to do both:
 
1.  Run a program with a dialog as a main window and have the program exit when I close that dialog.
2.  Run a program with a window frame that can pop up 1 or more dialogs and have that program close once all the dialogs are closed. (currently, closing the form does close all the dialogs, but not the app)

If there was only a frame, it closes just fine.

How can I close a (null parent) dialog box so that it doesn't keep the program running (message loop running) once all windows are closed.  I do not need the dialog box to cause a program exit, just not prevent a program exit.

In the following sample, if the form were a dialog or if a dialog(ok dialog) were created from within the form and then closed, the program keeps running with all windows closed.

```
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    public:
    bool OnInit();
private:
    void OnAboutClicked(wxCommandEvent &evt);
    MyFrame1 *myF;
};
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    if (!wxApp::OnInit())
        return false;
    myF = new MyFrame1(NULL);
    myF->Show();
    return true;
}
```

These do not help.

```
MyDialog1::~MyDialog1()
{
    //this->Destroy();
    //delete this;
}
```

Comment: Read about dialogs in wxWidgets and several similar questions around dialogs.  I read that the program will end once all (top level) windows are closed.  Forms, yes, dialogs, no.  I don't know exactly what it is that keeps the program going.

Comment: By default the program exits when the last top level window, frame or dialog, is closed. This can be changed if desired but I think the default behaviour is documented pretty clearly.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887733/program-doesnt-terminate-correctly?rq=1) could imply that I am creating some object(s) on a dialog and that those (windows) remain (not destroyed by the deconstructor).  I'll have to look at whether I orphan buttons or something.

Comment: Remaining note: with multiple NULL parent dialogs open, closing the frame created in MyApp hides those dialogs making it rather difficult to close them which could/would terminate the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem arises from dialogs, when top level, do not behave the same as top level forms.  It is pretty simple to change the dialog to destroy itself when the window is closed.  You can call a delete this in the OnClose event for the window and it will do the trick.  It only takes one window to keep the program running.

Connect a function (or other) to the close window event

```
//this may be in the object constructor or other appropriate place
this->Connect( wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, wxCloseEventHandler( MyDialog1::OnClose ) );
//an example of a similar Bind call looks like
this->Bind(wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, &MyDialog1::OnClose, this);
```

The function or member used can be as simple as delete this;.

```
//located in the dialog class definition
virtual void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event) { delete this; }
```

This shows that objects/windows were not being destroyed.  This approach is useful when not tracking all dialogs created and when they're modeless because each one will clean up itself.  This cleaned up objects (which no longer had a UI to close them) which were keeping the program running.

Note: it is recommended to use Bind instead of Connect.  See [this wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_evt_handler.html#a0f30c8fa5583b4a5f661897d63de3b62) description on Bind for rationale.